# Best way to view tomcat logs from web

Tags: logging, web, tomcat, viewer

There is a tomcat installation. There is need to view its logs (catalina.out and maybe some more) through web.

There is a way to set up apache webserver to look into folder and return logs as plaintext.

Is there more elegant way? Maybe tomcat itself can publish its logs to web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **psi-probe**, is an "Advanced manager and monitor for Apache Tomcat"

Here is the link: [Psi-Probe](https://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/)

Comment: This tool is great for viewing logs. But it can do much more: deploy and restart apps and so on. Is there a way to restrict a logged-in user to "just view logs"? Or maybe turn off everything except view-log functionality? Could not find it out from its docs